# How to execute and show tex-code within a question on tex.stackexchange.com?

Tags: discussion

I often see question and answeres where below or top of the code is a the generated output (PDF) of the tex code. How can I do that? ;)

Comment: We compile the code and create a screen-shot of the pdf viewer, or convert the pdf into png. For example, I use [Shutter](http://shutter-project.org/)

Comment: This is covered by http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4564/how-do-i-get-latex-output-to-show-up-on-tex-se?lq=1